# Biquery can't get list of datasets across all projects in a region from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, information-schema

According to the [documentation](https://When%20you%20query%20the%20INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA%20view,%20the%20query%20results%20contain%20one%20row%20for%20each%20dataset%20in%20a%20project%20to%20which%20the%20current%20user%20has%20access.) it says

> When you query the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA view, the query results contain one row for each dataset in a project to which the current user has access.

so I'm executing this query in BigQuery console

```
SELECT * FROM region-asia-southeast2.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA;
```

This region has a lot of projects, but the query returns data only for the current project selected in the console (in top left). If I change the project in console, it returns the results for the new project, so clearly, I have access to all the projects.
How can I query to fetch the datasets for *all projects* in a region?

Comment: You can get data for only one project per query, get a list of all projects, and then loop through it or use bigquery API